# Help with regex to find numbers

Tags: regex, vim, numbers

I'm trying to find all single numbers (with the use of vim):

- numbers at start of line
- numbers at end of line
- the number has to be followed and proceded by a non number
- but may not be folowed or proceded with a "dot" and a number or a "," and a number.

**this is correct**
7
word7
7word
7.
.7
a,7
word7word
word 7 word
7-7

**but not this**
7.7
7,7
77

Can anyone help me and explain the regex?

**EDIT:**
may'be I've found it with the help of an answer below about atomic grouping. Vim does support it:
`\(\d\.\|\d\,\|\d\)\@<!\d\(\.\d\|\,\d\|\d\)\@!`

Comment: A lot of regexs but can't find the solution. This is my latest but it doesn't do the job: `\(^\|[^,.0-9]\zs\)\d\{1}\(\ze[^,.0-9]\|$\)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\v%(\d+%(\.|,))@<!\d@<!\d+@>%(%(\.|,)\d)@!
```

Explanation:

- `\v` turns very magic : no need of many backslashes
- the `%` signs are optional (make groups in parentheses non-matching)
- `(\d+(\.|,)@<!` : not preceded with digits then . or ,
- `\d@<!` : not preceded with a digit (be sure we are at the first digit
- \d+@> : consume all digits (`@>` ensures that, see `:help /\@>`)
- `((\.|,)\d)@!` : after that, no dot or comma followed by a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl:

`^(?!\d(\.|\,)?\d)(((\D*?)\d(\D*?))|(\d(\D*?)\d))$`

And let me know if you'd like an explanation.

Comment: I'd rather have confirmation that it works for the OP's scenario before I begin to dissect it.

Comment: @jerluc, Is it a vim regex? It gives "pattern not found".

Comment: You may need to add back slashes, although I guess I'm not 100% that vim supports atomic groupings like `(?!...)`

Comment: That one's easy: vim doesn't support (?!...).

Comment: Then to avoid the atomic group: `^((\D*?)\d(\D*?)|(\d[^0-9,\.]+\d))$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
\(\d[\.,]\)\@<!\d\@<!\d\d\@!\([\.,]\d\)\@!
```

Explanation:

```
It looks for digits (\d) that are not preceeded by a '.' or ',' followed by a digit (\(\d[\.,]\)\@<!) or a single digit (\d\@<!), and is not followed by '.' or ',' followed by a digit (\([\.,]\d\)\@!) or a single digit (\d\@!).
```

This one is straight from my vim so it should work in yours.

Comment: This does work for his given examples, but a quick extrapolation from his written rules quickly takes a dive: `7a7`

Comment: sure, but what makes you believe that you know better than me how to extrapolate the rules? And following the KISS principle, this is the right way to start. It is easy to expand the regex to match further cases from here.

Comment: The rules are stated clearly. And KISS is no excuse for lack of upholding requirements.